# Сделать запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: запрос, mysql

Добрый день.
Есть две таблицы:

1 - Календарь

```
id | team1 | team2
1  |   1   |  2
2  |   3   |  4
3  |   4   |  1
```

2 - Команды

```
id | team_cod | team
1  |    1     |  Динамо
2  |    2     |  Спартак
3  |    3     |  Локомотив
4  |    4     |  ЦСКА
```

Как правильно создать запрос для выборки данных из этих двух таблиц в строчку, т.е.

```
1 | Динамо - Спартак
2 | Локомотив - ЦСКА
3 | ЦСКА - Динамо
```

Comment: хачем хранить team1 и team2 полем если можно сделать связи, может лучше опишите задачу. 

Comment: Задача составить календарь хоккейного турнира. Каждый матч это пара команд. Команды находятся в одной таблице, у каждой команды есть свой id_teams. В таблице календарь пары в полях teams1 и teams2.
То есть пара это 22(id_teams Спартак) и 33 (id_teams Динамо). Вот и задача вывести пару команд.

Comment: так а в чем проблема? Если вам нужны все возможные пары, то используйте обычный [CROSS JOIN][1]

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#CROSS_JOIN

Comment: вот уж целый день JOINы изучаю, но не выходит каменный цветок......

Comment: вам, как я опнимаю, нужно что-то такое:

    select t.Name, t1.Name
    from teams t
    cross join teams t1
    where t.Id != t1.Id

Comment: У вас каждая пара команд играет один раз или два? Иными словами, важен ли порядок: "Динамо - Спартак" и "Спартак - Динамо" - это одно и тоже или нет? Если нет, т.е., порядок важен - см. предыдущий ответ предложенный @DreamChild;  если порядок не важен замените != на <

Comment: Заработал следующий запрос:
SELECT 
    g.*,
  
    t1.teams AS home_team_name,
    t2.teams AS guest_team_name
FROM
    baza_calendar AS g
    INNER JOIN baza_teams AS t1 ON g.hoz = t1.id_teams
    INNER JOIN baza_teams AS t2 ON g.gos = t2.id_teams

Но у меня следующий вопрос - как их объединить? что-то вроде
CONCAT_WS(' - ', home_team_name, guest_team_name)

Никак не получается.

Comment: @DreamChild, [утверждается][1], что данный синтаксис устарел:

> Таким образом, CROSS JOIN + WHERE(предикат) и INNER JOIN(предикат)
> синтаксически являются альтернативными формами записи одной и той же
> логической операции внутреннего соединения. 
> Синтаксис CROSS JOIN + WHERE для операции соединения называют устаревшим, 
> поскольку его не рекомендует стандарт SQL ANSI.


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#CROSS_JOIN

Comment: Что-нибудь типа

     select a.id, concat_ws(' - ', b.team, c.team)
       from calend a
         join teams b on a.team1 = b.team_cod
         join teams c on a.team2 = c.team_cod
     order by a.id

Answer (score 1):

Делаем выборку из таблицы команд, повторно связываемся с таблицей команд через таблицу календарь.

```
select 
  t1.name,
  t2.name
from
  team as t1
  inner join calendar on (t1.team_cod = calendar.team1)
  inner join team as t2 on (calendar.team2 = t2.team_cod)
```